# Power BI if column equals this and greater than that then Percentage

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to do an if statement in a Power Bi Measure.

See data below. If [Type] = "CD" && [Days] >= 5 then divide by the total number of "CD"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmNz7.png)

[image]

So the answer should be there are 7 CD and 2 are greater than or equal to 6 so that would be %85

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

The total number of `CD` would be

```
Total Number of CD = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Type]); FILTER('Table'; 'Table'[Type] = "CD"))
```

The number of `CD >= 5` are:

```
Total Number of CD greater 5 = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Type]); FILTER('Table'; 'Table'[Type] = "CD" && 'Table'[Days] >= 5))
```

The percentage then would be:

```
Percentage = [Total Number of CD greater 5] / [Total Number of CD]
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much. The only issue I am now having, is if the answer is 0%, it does not display anything. Thoughts?

Comment: Drag all three measures in a KPI visual and check what their value is. This should tell you if there is a mistake.

Comment: I have done this. it works perfectly if the criteria is met. But if the answer is 0 are over the 5 days, then it displays nothing (blank)

Comment: You can put a check in front: `IF(YourCalculation = BLANK(), 0, YourCalculation)`